# Why does the Honda 2017 CR-V crawl in neutral when cold?

Tags: engine, honda, transmission, crv, cvt-transmission

In the owner's manual for the Honda 2017 CR-V, the shifting page says this:
[image]

Indeed, on a flat surface in neutral when the engine is cold, it will crawl forward like a typical automatic car in drive. Why is this?

I think that it is because it is has a CVT transmission that doesn't really have a neutral. It's a car with a torque converter with a lot of slip. At a stoplight, the engine runs at 700 rpm, but when you take your foot off the brake, there's a moment when the car doesn't move, then the rpm automatically increases to around 1100 rpm and it artificially crawls. Usually, in neutral, it is at around 700 rpm, but it will be at around 1000 rpm when cold.

Strangely, revving the engine to around 2000 rpm will not accelerate the car in neutral additionally when cold. So I'm not really sure.

Comment: Maybe it’s not related to the engine speed at all, the cvt has 2 clutches so I would think that they can be disconnected and stop driving the wheels, because if you shift into neutral at say 100mph I’m sure the engine wouldn’t over-rev, that’s just my $0.02!!